# R stat_smooth all points

Tags: r, ggplot2

From [Plot vectors of different length with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768556/plot-vectors-of-different-length-with-ggplot2/9769201#9769201), I've got my plot with lines.

```
ggplot(plotData, aes(x, y, label=label, group=label)) + geom_line() + stat_smooth()
```

But this smooths one line each. How do I smooth over all data points?

Comment: I see you've been asking a lot of rather similar questions in the last 24 hours.  Perhaps you could benefit from spending a little more time with the R tutorials, such as https://sites.google.com/site/r4statistics/example-programs/graphics-ggplot2  and http://egret.psychol.cam.ac.uk/statistics/R/graphs2.html .

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
ggplot(plotData, aes(x, y, label=label, group=label)) + 
    geom_line() +
    geom_smooth(aes(group = 1))
```

should do it. The idea here is to provide a new group aesthetic so that the fitted smoother is based on all the data, not the `group = label` aesthetic.

Following the example from [@Andrie's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9769201/429846) the modification I propose would be:

```
ggplot(plotData, aes(x, y, label=label, group=label)) + 
    geom_text() + 
    geom_smooth(aes(group = 1))
```

which would produce:

[image]