# how to plot individual density plot and them combine them into one with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I have a large table to plot (rows are measurements at different places and columns are different samples) and the table is huge with 30 million rows and 60 columns. I can draw density plot for each group with a smaller data set but this full file is just too huge to handle if I read everything into memory at once.

The data looks like this:

```
      variable value
1       V5  0.95
2       V5  0.98
3       V5  0.98
4       V5  0.95
5       V5  0.98
6       V5  0.98
```

The R code to draw is:

```
 ggplot(df2.m,aes(x=value,colour=variable))+geom_density(alpha=.2)+theme_bw()+theme(text=element_text(size=30),panel.border=element_rect(linetype="solid",colour="black",size=2.8),panel.grid.major=element_line(size=1.2),axis.ticks=element_line(size=1.4),axis.ticks.length=unit(.5,"cm"),legend.position="none")
```

I'm wondering how can I draw density plot for each group first and save the object or something into a temporary thing and do all the samples and them combine them into one plot?

Comment: this post answered my question essentially. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199919/overlapped-density-plots-in-ggplot2

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to try this better-looking solution:

[How to overlay density plots in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939136/how-to-overlay-density-plots-in-r)

By including the `fill` option in the `aes` argument of the `ggplot` function it helps highlight the overlap.

Comment: this was not done using ggplot2.. i know how to do this in regular R but it doesn't seem possible to use ggplot2 to handle large files yet

Comment: @olala Sorry, I was referring to the second answer down which does use ggplot2.